# I have multiple realm paths and I want to delete it all, is there an easy way to delete all realm paths?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I have multiple realm paths per account (Inventory System with different branches) and I want to delete it all when a user logs out.

Currently, I have this delete function but it only deletes the current path based on the current databaseConfig().

```
export const emptyDatabase = () => new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
 Realm.open(databaseConfig())
  .then((realm: any) => {
    realm.write(() => {
      realm.deleteAll();
      resolve();
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    reject(error);
  });
});

export const databaseConfig = () => {
 const branch: any = store.getState().branchReducer.branch;
 return {
  path: `${branch?.branch_id}.realm`,
  schema: [
  ...
  ],
  schemaVersion: 0,
 };
};
```

Is there an easy way to delete all path? My other option is to loop this function with all paths but I don't think it is a clean solution.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you saying you have multiple Realm files stored locally and you want to delete all of them at the same time? Are they all stored in the same location or all all of the paths different? Please update the QUESTION with more details. Oh, also, do you store the path/paths somewhere?